# How to join three table in laravel eloquent?

Tags: sql, laravel, join, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have three tables:

```
consignee (id,name) , jobs(id,consignee_id), expenses(id,job_id)
```

In my `ExpensesController`

```
public function index(){
        $expenses = \App\Expense::all();
        return view('expenses.index', compact('expenses'));}
```

in my index view page i want get all the details in expenses table with consignee name now  in my view page

```
@foreach($expenses as $expense)
<tr>
  <td width="5%">{!! $expense->id !!}</td>
<td width="7%">{!! $expense->date !!}</td>
<td width="7%">{!! $expense->job_id !!}</td>
<td width="10%">{!!$expense-> !!}</td></tr>
                        @endforeach
```

i dont know how to get consignee name in my index view any one suggest me idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$expenses = \App\Expense::all();
```

you can use:

```
$expenses = \App\Expense::select('expenses.*','consignee.name')
            ->leftJoin('jobs','jobs.id','=','expenses.job_id')
            ->leftJoin('consignee','consignee.id','=','jobs.consignee_id') 
            ->get();
```

This way you make join with 2 other tables and get name of Consignee.

Comment: ok and how to use this out put in my view to get **name**? in here `<td width="10%">{!!$expense-> !!}</td></tr>`

Comment: @HamelRaj  Simply `{!! $expense->name !!}`

Comment: in json i will get the name:" " but when i use `{!!$expense->name !!}` empty  nothing output??

Comment: @HamelRaj  Are you sure you are getting any result from DB? Run `SELECT expenses.*, consignee.name FROM expenses LEFT JOIN jobs ON jobs.id = expenses.job_id LEFT JOIN consignee ON consignee.id = jobs.consignee_id` and you will see what you have in your database.

Comment: very very sorry sir thatz my mistak thankyou somuch :)

Comment: @HamelRaj Glad I could help :)